# Tangent of circumscribed circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

I found a solution online which it said :
"It's easy noted that $AG.AE$ = $AD^2$ = $AF^2$ (Using tangent of circumscribed circle)"

I found this not obvious at all. I know that $AD = AF$ but why it had to equal to the product of two inline line?

Comment: do you want proof of this therom?but proof is also simple just using pythgoreous theorem in different right angle triangle.And that line AE called as secant line

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the keyword. I found a Wikipedia entry which I will use to answer my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found it! It's called **"secant-tangent theorem", "intersecting chords theorem"**, or the **"power-of-a-point theorem".** Which you can learn in this link..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point

Comment: to proove it takes just two right angle triangle